# How do I force merge contacts in Google Contacts?

Tags: google-contacts

[Google Contacts](https://contacts.google.com) automatically identifies potential duplicates and supports [merging](https://contacts.google.com/merge) these candidates, but I can't figure out how to force or suggest candidates for merging.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to Contacts.   Search so that you can see both/all of the contacts you want to merge on the one results screen.

Click the checkbox on the left hand size of the screen for the contacts you want to merge.

From the More menu (at the top of the list of contacts), choose Merge Contacts.

Like this:  [image]

Comment: Currently, I think you have to click "Go to old version" to do this. I can't find a way to do it in the new version.

Comment: The question was about the automtic detection and merge suggestion process.  This answer is about manual merge.

Comment: The answer actually matches the question perfectly

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to https://contacts.google.com/
2. Select contacts to merge &
3. Click Branch Sign as shown in figure below:

[image]

Comment: This is a manual merge. The questions was about automatic process.

Comment: The answer actually matches the question perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Merge duplicates
If you have duplicate listings for the same person in Google Contacts, you can merge them.

Go to Google Contacts.
On the left, click Duplicates. If you don’t see Duplicates, go to merge contacts in old Contacts.
In the top right, click Merge all. Or, review each duplicate and click Merge.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open your Contacts List
2. Hover over the icon/avatar image that appears on the left of your contact.  This displays a 'radio' box.  Click this to check and select the contact.
3. Scroll to, and repeat for the other contact / contacts you want to merge together.
4. Click the branch symbol that appears at the top of the contacts page in a temporary bar (it is a vertical blue arrow with an extra leg and shows after the second selection).
5. Merging will now take place
6. You will have to check name details because some will be over-written by the process
7. Done.  21 July 2020.